# Can't install or run html-pdf on nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm, html-pdf, node-html-pdf

I have a application that generates PDF's using `html-pdf` on nodejs, but after I made a deploy to the production server, I'm not able to generate. It gives this error:

> 'html-pdf: Failed to load PhantomJS module. You have to set the path
>   to the PhantomJS binary using 'options.phantomPath'

And if I run `npm install html-pdf` again, it gives this error

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node@11.8.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the node@11.8.0 preinstall script.
```

And this error replicates to other modules, but I made a turn around.

Runing node 13.7.0 and npm 6.9.0

Comment: If you can’t make this work, I’d also recommend Puppeteer to help with this purpose. It’s been my go-to for server-side HTML to PDF.

Comment: Are you running node 13.7 or 11.8?  Your logs say something different than your text.

Comment: PhantomJS is dead, use Puppeteer, as @stephancasas suggested. Also I recommend giving a try for Gotenberg — this is Docker-powered API for converting to PDF, and I wrote small JS/TS client for it — https://github.com/yumauri/gotenberg-js-client

Answer (score 1):

Can you try again with the `-g` flag

```
npm install -g html-pdf
```

If still not working, execute after that:

```
npm link html-pdf
npm link phantomjs-prebuilt
```

from https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/437#issuecomment-467463285